# It is possible to use the Google´s sites full size with a Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, google-gadget

I have developed a site with Google´s Apps Script, however, I need to put this within a Google site, the problem is when I insert the Apps Script's URL in the Google´s site this is not allowing to the script takes the full size of the page. Is there any form to do this? Thank you very much for all the help and orientation that you can give me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the code snippet then we will able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you [embed web app in Google Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?csw=1#embedding_your_web_app_in_google_sites) that is only an iframe, you can define the height and width, but you're still limited to the size of the page. You can always link directly to the web app URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help friend, yes. Actually I thought to do that, but my site is going to be hosted into a Google site which hosts other sites, then, when you are looking for my "page" this appears like a shared file (Apps Script). For this reason I need to wrap the script within a site.

Comment: You can set the Site layout to 100% width and then your gadget also to 100% width (this will affect all your Site), the only disadvantage is you can't set the height  of the gadget to 100%, you will need to set it to the maxim height you expect in your Web App. Hopefully the [New version of Google Sites](http://googleforwork.blogspot.mx/2016/06/powering-a-more-connected-and-collaborative-enterprise.html) include more options to embed apps scripts.